# Importing JQuery in typescript

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, typescript

Just found out about Typescript, and after messing around with it I decided that I wanted to test it with JQuery and OMG I can't make it work.

The instructions seems fairly simple: Get jquery.d.ts -> Add it to the project -> Add `/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />`

It seems to work fairly well, auto-complete and everything. The only issue is that the code won't compile. This is the error I'm getting: `0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined`

This is the Jquery.d.ts that I'm using: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts

And here's my code:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
class Greeter {
element: HTMLElement;
span: HTMLElement;
img: HTMLElement;
timerToken: number;

constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
    this.element = element;
    this.element.innerHTML += "The time is: ";
    this.span = document.createElement('span');
    this.img = document.createElement('img');
    this.img.setAttribute('src', "http://static5.businessinsider.com/image/52447d4becad0431644a8db2-1200/sean-raiger-of-sacramento-won-silver-for-the-partial-imperial-beard.jpg");
    this.img.setAttribute('style', "height:500px;width:500px;");
    this.element.appendChild(this.span);
    this.span.innerText = new Date().toUTCString();
    this.element.appendChild(this.img);
    $('img').click((event: JQueryEventObject) => { this.span.innerHTML = "aaaaaa"});
    //$(this.img).click(ActOnClick($(this.img)));
}

start() {
    this.timerToken = setInterval(() => this.span.innerHTML = new Date().toUTCString(), 500);
}

stop() {
    clearTimeout(this.timerToken);
}

}


window.onload = () => {
    var el = document.getElementById('content');
    var greeter = new Greeter(el);
    greeter.start();
};
```

Comment: You'll need to include the current `jquery.js` in your HTML page in a `script` tag. The `.d.ts` is just the interface definition file, it does not contain the jQuery functionality.

Comment: Well that's a shame. But adding `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` before `<script src="app.js"></script>` in default.html doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Could you clarify -- is this at runtime or compile time? The error suggests run-time, but you said it was at compile time.

Comment: Yeah you were right it was at runtime. However the code now works, which is weird since I tried to run it after adding the script tags. I'll just say that maybe a clean/recompile with the extra tags fixed it. If you write your comment as a response I can mark it as solved

Comment: why is this tagged `c#`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you've included the script for jQuery on your HTML page:

```
<script src="/assets/jQuery.min.js"></script>
```

The `.d.ts` files serve only as the definition for jQuery and not the actual implementation. If you load the jQuery JavaScript files before your compiled Typescript => JavaScript files, it should work without issue (you may need to clear your browser cache/refresh the web page if it doesn't work immediately).